# How are ajax options supposed to be added to a UActiveForm?

Tags: php, yii

I've looked in the framework documentation and yii forums, but can't seem to find anything on this. I am trying to add ajax options to a UActiveForm widget. To put it another way, I want a loading gif to be inserted into a div when the submit button of this ajax form is clicked. I know how to do this in raw javascript/jquery/php, but I can't seem to get this done with this framework. Here is my begin widget code:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('UActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'login-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        'validateOnChange'=>false,
        'validateOnType'=>false,
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data','class'=>'white-popup-block'),
    ),
)); ?>

<!--form labels/inputs here-->

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Below is what part of my ajax code looks like if I am do to it without a framework:

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: "usersystem/login.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: serializedData,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#loader').show();
        $('button').off(); //unbind all buttons
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('#loader').hide();
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#test').append(data);
    }
});
```

What I want in particular is the beforeSend and complete ajax options. I have tried simply adding

```
'ajax'=> array(
    'beforeSend'=> 'function() {
        alert("testing, ready");
    }',
    'complete'=> 'function(){
        alert("testing,done");
    }',
),
```

to the UActiveForm widget options, but it doesn't work. I would appreciate any help in trying to understand this framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what a `UActiveForm` is, but assuming it's some kind of `CActiveForm` there are `beforeValidate` and `afterValidate` options that you can use as part of `clientOptions`:

```
'clientOptions'=>array(
    'beforeValidate' => new CJavaScriptExpression('function() { ... })'),
    'afterValidate' => new CJavaScriptExpression('function() { ... })'),
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    'validateOnChange'=>false,
    'validateOnType'=>false,
),
```

You need to wrap the function code inside a `CJavaScriptExpression` because otherwise Yii will treat it as a string and `json_encode` it.

Comment: Thanks! That works, but now the ajax post does not get sent, strangely enough...Do you have any insight as to why this is? If not, I will continue debugging...

Comment: Ah, never mind. I figured it out. It turns out that the anonymous javascript function needs to return true in order for the form to continue. Otherwise, it does nothing and stops in its tracks.